# Change audio card on pyalsaaudio

Tags: python, linux, fedora, alsa

I need to change the audio device used on a python script. I'm using alsaaudio, and according to this http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/libalsaaudio.html this is achieved just by entering the card name when creating the PCM device. When I type on Python

```
import alsaaudio
alsaaudio.cards()
```

I get

```
[u'Intel', u'Q9000']
```

but creating the PCM object as

```
alsaaudio.PCM(aa.PCM_CAPTURE, aa.PCM_NORMAL, 'Q9000')
```

it returns

```
Unknown PCM default:CARD=Q9000
```

I've tried to modify the .asoundrc for having the configuration I want as default, but while it works with aplay and arecord on Python the default audio device is still the same.

On ~/.asoundrc I put

```
pcm.quicktimeWebCam
{
    type hw
    card Q9000
}

pcm.internal
{
    type hw
    card Intel
}

pcm.!default
{
    type asym
    playback.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "internal"
    }
    capture.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "quicktimeWebCam"
    }
}
```

Comment: And what did you do in your `.asoundrc`?

Comment: I escaped the issue by changing the default audio settings on the sound manager... but basically in the .asoundrc I did the same as here.. http://atgn.tumblr.com/post/54588497569/how-to-set-default-audio-input-output-devices-on (which worked fine on my raspberry Pi, with Debian)

Comment: I added the content on .asoundrc, I have the same problem on Fedora18

Comment: I'd be interested if you've come to a solution meanwhile.

Answer (score 3):

ALSA devices are represented by "hw:x,y", where x is the device and y is the subdevice (if any). It is expecting the card to be specified in the form of "hw:x,y", and not the human readable name.

```
card_info = {}
for device_number, card_name in enumerate(alsaaudio.cards()):
    card_info[card_name] = "hw:%s,0" % device_number

device = alsaaudio.PCM(card=card_info["Q9000"])
```

Comment: The `card` kwarg has been deprecated in favour of `device`, so the last line should read `device = alsaaudio.PCM(device=card_info["Q9000"]) for newer versions of python-alsaaudio

Answer (score 0):

Device names for `alsaaudio` have some undocumented quirks;
when you use a plain card ID (as returned by `cards()`), it is expected that you have a `default` device that accepts a card parameter.
(The default `default` supports this parameter.)

To use a specific device, use `plug:internal` or `plug:quicktimeWebCam`.

Comment: thanks for your answer CL, I've tried to put
`alsaaudio.PCM(aa.PCM_CAPTURE, aa.PCM_NORMAL, 'plug:internal` instead of `alsaaudio.PCM(aa.PCM_CAPTURE, aa.PCM_NORMAL, 'Q9000')` but I still get the `invalid value for card` error

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem and is a reported [bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyalsaaudio/bugs/8/).  The confusion lies in what alsaaudio's PCM object expects for the card argument.  As the mentioned wiki would have you believe it is the desired card's name (technically ALSA calls this the ID).  This is true as long as you have defined the card name as a control for the default device profile in the [.asoundrc](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc) you are using.

On the other hand the card argument can accept the whole of a PCM handle as alluded to by CL above.  As seen in the mentioned bug there is a patch submitted that would add this PCM handle identification functionality.  Until that is added to the module a good way to determine the correct handle to pass to the PCM objects is by looking at the output of `arecord -L` (or possibly `aplay -L` if looking for a playback device name).